# How to speed up Symfony 2 functional test suites?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a very simple CRUD functional test suite for each and every controller in my bundles. I have two methods, setUpBeforeClass where i create a new database, create a new schema and then populate the schema with fixtures, and setUpAfterClass, where i remove the database.

Each controller test is taking about 1:30 minutes. Any ideas of how to speed this up? I can't use SQLite because i'm using complex relationships not supported by it.

Comment: I have identified the bottleneck in my description. It's database, schema and fixture loading. If you didn't read it, please, don't make stupid and destructive comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i could see, you just have a bunch of YourEntityControllerTest.php in the Tests folder of your bundles and a pair of setUpBeforeClass/setUpAfterClass methods for each test file, setting up and then destroying the database. Right?

You could dramatically speed this up by creating an actual test suite, see: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/organizing-test-suites.html#organizing-test-suites.suite-level-setup

Comment: If you don't use the profiler in your test, you can disable it in you r test environement by editing `config_test.yml` :

    framework
        profiler:
            enabled: false

Comment: Updated link: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html